# Probability puzzle with cards

Tags: probability

Given one hundred cards with numbers 1-100 on each card and two baskets, you throw each of these cards with 50% of probability falling in the left basket and 50% to the right. What is the expected value of the minimum number in the left basket?

My thoughts are:

Let S be the r.v. corresponding to the minimum number in the left basket.
Then $E(S) = \sum_{s=0}^{100} P(S > s)$. For s > 0, I think the probability that S > s is $\frac{1}{2^s}$, because this event happens when the numbers 1, 2, ..., s all landed in the right basket. I think $P(S > 0) = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{100}}$ because the minimum number is greater than 0 as long as any card landed in the left bin. Does this seem correct?

---

**Extension**

What changes if we ask what is the expected value of the minimum in the basket that contains the number 100?

Comment: There is some ambiguity in the question statement on how to handle the case when no cards fall into the left basket.

Comment: Yes I wasn't sure what to do about that.

Comment: I think it's fair to assume/add that the minimum value of the empty set is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there are $n$ cards with numbers from $1$ to $n$ and the probability of any of them falling into the left basket is $p$.

Suppose, that when you toss cards you start with the smallest numbers, so that the number of the toss coincides with the number f the card tossed (we can do this, because all cards are tossed independently and their actual order does not determine anything). Suppose $X_i$ is $1$ if card with number $i$ is in the left basket and $0$ otherwise.

Then the minimal number in the left basket will be $\min\{i| X_i = 1\}$ if it is non empty, and $0$ otherwise (the probability of which is $(1-p)^n$)

Then for any $k < n$ the probability that $\min\{i| X_i = 1\} = k$ is $(1-p)^{k-1}p$.

Thus, your expectation is $\sum_{k = 1}^n k(1-p)^{k-1}p$.

EDIT 1:

There is also a way to calculate the same number differently (with the method, that OP was using).

The probability, that $\min\{i| X_i = 1\} \geq k$ for $k \in 1 ... n$ is the probability, that $X_1 = ... = X_{k-1} = 0$, but $\max{X_k, ... , x_n} = 1$. And that is $(1-p)^{k-1}(1 - (1-p)^{n-k + 1}) = (1-p)^{k-1} - (1-p)^n$.

Thus our expectation can be alternatively expressed as $$\sum_{k = 1}^n P(\min\{i| X_i = 1\} \geq k) = \sum_{k = 1}^n ((1-p)^{k-1} - (1-p)^n) = \frac{1 - (1-p)^n}{p} - n(1-p)^n$$

Thus we get an alternative solution, as well as prove algebraic identity

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n k(1-p)^{k-1}p = \frac{1 - (1-p)^n}{p} - n(1-p)^n$$

EDIT 2:

If there is already have a card with number $n+1$ in the basked before we started tossing the cards, then the only value different will be the value in the case when $X_1 = ... = X_n = 0$ (it will change from $0$ t $n+1$). Because the probability of this event is $(1-p)^n$ the expectation will increase by $(n+1)(1 - p)^n$ and become

$$\frac{1 - (1-p)^n}{p} - n(1-p)^n + (n+1)(1-p)^n = \frac{1 - (1-p)^n}{p} + (1-p)^n = \frac{1 - (1-p)^{n+1}}{p}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I worked this out, the final answer came out different to what I got using the approach in the question. Can you see any issues with the reasoning I outlined there? I've also added an extension and I'm not sure how it changes the puzzle. If you have time it would be really useful if you could take a look! :)

Comment: @asfjbkjabf, I edited the answer to address those additional questions.